# Cannot find spark image built with docker-image-tool locally

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to build spark image to use with Kubernetes (minikube locally) (following https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html, https://itnext.io/running-spark-job-on-kubernetes-minikube-958cadaddd55 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/spark-job).
I want to build it for local docker repo and I am using following command `./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -m -t v2 build` to build it for minikube. This build succeeds, but after that I can't find the image with `docker image ps`. The spark-submit fails with cryptic `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main`, which doesn't tell anything, but it seems reasonable to be linked with image missing in the docker registry.

All *build* steps seem to succeed with no issue, so I am bit lost at what went wrong.

Build output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.193GB
Step 1/15 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim
 ---> 6b2212023a6e
Step 2/15 : ARG spark_jars=jars
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2407ea1f6efa
Step 3/15 : ARG img_path=kubernetes/dockerfiles
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db7404f15dfd
Step 4/15 : ARG k8s_tests=kubernetes/tests
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8dc19efc9230
Step 5/15 : RUN set -ex &&     apt-get update &&     ln -s /lib /lib64 &&     apt install -y bash tini libc6 libpam-modules libnss3 &&     mkdir -p /opt/spark &&     mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir &&     touch /opt/spark/RELEASE &&     rm /bin/sh &&     ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh &&     echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su &&     chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd &&     rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5884173cd551
Step 6/15 : COPY ${spark_jars} /opt/spark/jars
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ff058e0c80e7
Step 7/15 : COPY bin /opt/spark/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d158732d730c
Step 8/15 : COPY sbin /opt/spark/sbin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 896cd481cdbc
Step 9/15 : COPY ${img_path}/spark/entrypoint.sh /opt/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1d108a1e1df4
Step 10/15 : COPY examples /opt/spark/examples
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3a7680f04b03
Step 11/15 : COPY ${k8s_tests} /opt/spark/tests
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cd76b303d3e
Step 12/15 : COPY data /opt/spark/data
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8221e20aac95
Step 13/15 : ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ecb9bee32447
Step 14/15 : WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6bfafec8d0bb
Step 15/15 : ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 110ccecb98db
Successfully built 110ccecb98db
Successfully tagged spark:v2
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.193GB
Step 1/9 : ARG base_img
Step 2/9 : FROM $base_img
 ---> 110ccecb98db
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d82c43a71b8
Step 4/9 : RUN mkdir ${SPARK_HOME}/python
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a06db167de65
Step 5/9 : RUN apt install -y python python-pip &&     apt install -y python3 python3-pip &&     rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip &&     pip install --upgrade pip setuptools &&     rm -r /root/.cache && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2789da56886a
Step 6/9 : COPY python/lib ${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 17ad5567580c
Step 7/9 : ENV PYTHONPATH ${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/pyspark.zip:${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-*.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 01f0ee91d6a6
Step 8/9 : WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95b4885abc7e
Step 9/9 : ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2bb9c23681e8
Successfully built 2bb9c23681e8
Successfully tagged spark-py:v2
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.193GB
Step 1/9 : ARG base_img
Step 2/9 : FROM $base_img
 ---> 110ccecb98db
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d82c43a71b8
Step 4/9 : RUN mkdir ${SPARK_HOME}/R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c49d10da5c74
Step 5/9 : RUN apt install -y r-base r-base-dev && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d693ef1ab12c
Step 6/9 : COPY R ${SPARK_HOME}/R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 50ca4b703501
Step 7/9 : ENV R_HOME /usr/lib/R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cba4fbc51e7c
Step 8/9 : WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 449edacaae16
Step 9/9 : ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a84c327a2b9d
Successfully built a84c327a2b9d
Successfully tagged spark-r:v2
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Comment: Did you manage to sort it out? What's Spark version? How do you spark-submit the Spark application?

Answer (score 1):

I have missed these as well. But this should be OK

You see the lines

```
Successfully tagged spark:v2
Successfully tagged spark-py:v2
Successfully tagged spark-r:v2
```

so your build has succeeded, and the Docker images for JVM-, Python- and R-based jobs to be used for Spark jobs on Kubernetes were created.

You will ***not*** see these images when you list the images ***on the host*** (the system *minikube* runs on):

```
$ docker image ls | egrep "spark-k8s-2.4.5|minikube"
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase                                          v0.0.18                                         a776c544501a        6 weeks ago         1.08GB
```

You should see these images when you list the images ***in minikube***:

```
$ minikube ssh
Last login: Thu Apr  8 15:55:10 2021 from 192.168.49.1
docker@minikube:~$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                TAG               IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
spark-r                                   spark-k8s-2.4.5   21836f5f1e0c   23 hours ago    1.1GB
spark-py                                  spark-k8s-2.4.5   1a042cd867f7   23 hours ago    1.05GB
spark                                     spark-k8s-2.4.5   07a9a8459c4c   23 hours ago    552MB
openjdk                                   8-jdk-slim        76fad6e75a0f   9 days ago      288MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                     v1.20.2           43154ddb57a8   2 months ago    118MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver                 v1.20.2           a8c2fdb8bf76   2 months ago    122MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager        v1.20.2           a27166429d98   2 months ago    116MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler                 v1.20.2           ed2c44fbdd78   2 months ago    46.4MB
kubernetesui/dashboard                    v2.1.0            9a07b5b4bfac   3 months ago    226MB
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner   v4                85069258b98a   4 months ago    29.7MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                           3.4.13-0          0369cf4303ff   7 months ago    253MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                        1.7.0             bfe3a36ebd25   9 months ago    45.2MB
kubernetesui/metrics-scraper              v1.0.4            86262685d9ab   12 months ago   36.9MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                          3.2               80d28bedfe5d   13 months ago   683kB
k8s.gcr.io/echoserver                     1.4               a90209bb39e3   4 years ago     140MB
```

This is the effect of using

```
docker-image-tool.sh -m
```

*-m* instructs *docker-image-tool.sh* to "use minikube's Docker daemon".

Likewise *docker ps* on the host will look like this: It will show *minikube*

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
3cb659bf50d7        gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.18   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   8 days ago          Up 56 minutes           127.0.0.1:32782->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32781->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32780->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32779->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32778->32443/tcp   minikube
```

O the other hand you should see various Kubernetes services in *minikube* like this:

```
$ minikube ssh
Last login: Fri Apr  9 06:59:08 2021 from 192.168.49.1
docker@minikube:~$ docker ps | head -n 5
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
43b8fa28c0f0   9a07b5b4bfac           "/dashboard --insecu…"   56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes             k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-968bcb79-hnqcg_kubernetes-dashboard_90252423-eb5d-4e53-800a-3aa40cbcd4b6_9
3cc6d85f88ce   85069258b98a           "/storage-provisioner"   56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes             k8s_storage-provisioner_storage-provisioner_kube-system_ca8a31c4-1ca2-4284-b9d4-4a1068d46876_15
cf48ca7b8e2e   bfe3a36ebd25           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes             k8s_coredns_coredns-74ff55c5b-xtkgf_kube-system_d24f114f-d3f9-4a45-bd2a-fa954a42686e_7
0ce17fa229df   a90209bb39e3           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes             k8s_echoserver_hello-minikube-6ddfcc9757-vwkh8_default_08c3f2ee-c0ed-4778-9aa9-5d65890cb18c_7
```

As for the error message I don't think that it's related to the "missing" image.
It could be anything, like invalid class name, the class is not the jar, dependency problems (for example in the jar file containing the job), mixed Spark versions etc.